# Internet Explorer 11 Google Maps certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate, google-maps

I know IE 11 is crap but you probably also got those old fashionned stubbern users that still use it. -_-'

So the story is this. User wants to use IE11 on Windows 7 to check the maps. Everything is fine and works but he still gets those annoying certificat alerts on google maps. Is there a way to turn of those messages or accept those certificates or whatever automaticly? I can reproduce this message as well so I don't have to waste his time while trying to figure this out.

Would be great to get that guy off my back with this one and yes I already tried to find a solution but no chance at all.

Comment: Tell him there is no solution and to use chrome or get use to the nags.

Comment: Can you share the steps you used to reproduce the issue? What error/warning is your user getting? I can load `https://maps.google.com` (which redirects to `https://www.google.com/maps`) just fine in IE 11 on Windows 7 with no certificate warnings or errors. The certificate looks quite normal.

Comment: So what I basicly did to check this on my pc. I opened IE 11, when to google. Searched for whatever town I wanted. Clicked on the link to maps. Waited a sec or two for the page to load. Getting the annoying message. The message is not the issue for me but for those who want to work with IE.